# Why is the $L_2$ regularization squared while the $L_1$ is not?

Tags: statistics, normed-spaces, regularization

Best example to demonstate my question is the elastic net, which has the Risk (here for linear regression). For some $D=\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ with $ x_i\in \mathbb{R}^d, y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \geq 0$.

$$R(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n (w^Tx_i -y_i)^2  + \lambda_1 ||w||_1 + \lambda_2 ||w||_2^2$$

Why is the $L_2$ norm squared, just because of the derivative, or is there some reason behind this?

Comment: The function $\| w \|_2^2$ is differentiable, whereas the function $\| w \|_2$ is not. On the other hand, squaring the $\ell_1$-norm will not make it differentiable, so there's no reason to do so.

Comment: There is also a statistical viewpoint to be aware of. If we view the parameter vector $w$ as a random vector and assume that the components of $w$ are independent, normally distributed random variables, then the squared $\ell_2$-penalty emerges from the details of maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimation for $w$. On the other hand, if we assume that the components of $w$ are independent and follow a Laplace distribution, then the $\ell_1$-penalty emerges when you work out the details of MAP estimation for $w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question also on a forum of my university. One thing an assistant mentioned:

The norm $||w||_1$ is linear in $|w_i|$ and $||w||^2$ is linear in $|w_i|^2$. Which makes the non-squared $L_1$ and squared $L_2$ norms computationally and theoretically more interesting and easier to handle.

Note that $||w||_1^2 = ||w||_2^2 + \sum_{j}\sum_{i\neq j}|w_j|\,|w_i|$ is not linear in $|w_i|$ and also $||w||_2$ itself is not linear in $|w_i|$. Thus squared $L_1$ and and non-squared $L_2$ are hard to handle.